# How to store additional data in the FormsAuthentication cookie?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, forms-authentication

I am retrieving the tenant name from the url. I'd prefer to do it only once, store it in the cookie, and retrieve it from there when I need it in a new page request.

I am using the code below to "create" a cookie. I was hoping that the interface would allow me to store additional information but it doesn't. Is there a way to do this or am I on the wrong track?

```
    public void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "userName");

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that later you'd like to add arbitrary data to the cookie?

Comment: Tempted to say yes. Shouldn't I?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Forty-Two got it, take a look at his answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't try to alter the Auth Cookie.  Instead, create a new cookie:

```
var myCookie = new HttpCookie("myCookie");//instantiate an new cookie and give it a name
myCookie.Values.Add("TenantName", "myTenantName");//populate it with key, value pairs
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);//add it to the client
```

Then you can read the value on that's written to the cookie like this

```
var cookie = Request.Cookies["myCookie"];
var tenantName = cookie.Values["TenantName"].ToString();
//tenantName = "myTenantName"
```

Comment: you get 3 votes. could I ask you to explain why this is better than the answer Tommy gave? Or is that a matter of taste?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the plugin Tommy is referring to, so I can't speak to it, or claim one way is 'better' than the other.  As for this method, it's quick and easy to implement, will be easy to maintain in the future, and doesn't change anything about the forms auth ticket

Comment: @Forty-Two - just wanted to throw in my 2 cents on my answer.  What is provided does not change anything about the FormsAuth ticket either, it simply puts the UserData property to use:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.userdata.aspx.  not going for a debate on either method with this, just a little clarification :)

Comment: @Tommy Understood, and to be clear, I didn't mean to imply that it did (change the auth ticket, that is).  I haven't checked out the project, so I can't speak to it one way or another.  I'm sure it does it's job, or you wouldn't have recommended it.  Cheers

Answer (score 14):

The FormsAuthenticationExtensions project on codeplex and on Nuget does exactly this.  [https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=formsauthext](https://web.archive.org/web/20210923115559/https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=formsauthext)

**Usage -Setting Values**

```
using FormsAuthenticationExtensions;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

var ticketData = new NameValueCollection
{
    { "name", user.FullName },
    { "emailAddress", user.EmailAddress }
};
new FormsAuthentication().SetAuthCookie(user.UserId, true, ticketData);
```

**Usage -Retrieving Values**

```
using FormsAuthenticationExtensions;
using System.Web.Security;

var ticketData = ((FormsIdentity) HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Ticket.GetStructuredUserData();
var name = ticketData["name"];
var emailAddress = ticketData["emailAddress"];
```

Basically, you can append a name/value dictionary inside of your FormsAuthentication cookie to store some frequently used values.  We leverage this store store a small subset of user information such as companyId, etc.

Additionally, there is no 'black magic' happening here, it is simply encapsulating the setting/retrieving of the [UserData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.userdata?view=netframework-4.8) property inside of the FormsAuthentication Ticket

As for consideration, please be sure to read the notes at the bottom of the project page as it describes why this should only be used for small amounts of long-living data.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll bookmark it and try it out later. I'll go for forty-two's answer for now. +1 tho. thx

Comment: For me it's giving an error at the line: var ticketData = ((FormsIdentity) User.Identity).Ticket.GetStructuredUserData();  Saying it can't associate an object to another

Comment: For me its giving an error at ticket value defined NameValueCollection. It saying "could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   " When I'm already defined the assembly.